# Telegram bot webhook and amazon lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, telegram-webhook

I've tried to create my first telegram bot hosting the code as an amazon lambda instance, i suppose i should return something to the webhook 'cause it keep saying "Wrong response from the webhook: 502 Bad Gateway".

Here is part of my code:

```js
def msgSend(text, chat_id):
    url = URL + "sendMessage?text={}&chat_id={}".format(text, chat_id)
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content.decode("utf8")
    return content


def handle(msg):
    sender = msg['from']['username']
    id_gruppo = msg['chat']['id']
    if sender == NAME:
        testo = msg['text']
        usernames = [x.replace('@','') for x in rx.findall(text)]
        map(foo, usernames)
        msgSend(confirm_mess, id_group)
        return


def main(event, context): 
    response = ast.literal_eval(event['body'])
    handle(response['message'])
    return {
        'something': 'something'
    }
```

Actually the process works fine enough, the messages are received by my lambda and everything works like a charm, except for one thing, the confirmation message is sent over and over endlessly and the webhooks never marks the messages as read.

here is the response of getWebHookInfo:
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://t2rt9guj3h.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/instabot","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":19,"last_error_date":1489331750,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 502 Bad Gateway","max_connections":40}}

According to the bot helper the wh requires a 2XX code response...

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the bot helper the wh requires a 2XX code response...

This is true. Your last statement should be

```
return {
    statusCode: 200
}
```

If you don't return a successful response code, Telegram won't know what to do with it, which is why you see the `HTTP 502 Bad Gateway`. I was hitting this for awhile also :)